# If a number exists in one column, look up a value in a different column that corresponds with the number

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

In Sheets I have one column that contains User Key paths exported from a database. An example User Key looks like this:

Column A:

`"Organization", "example.com", "User", 6682660647665664`

Then in another part of the Sheet I have two columns: One with a list of the numbers from the User Keys and in the second column the corresponding user name for that user. Example:

Column B:

`6682660647665664`

Column C: `John Doe`

What I'm looking for is a function that will search through Column A, find the number (i.e. '6682660647665664') and then look up the real user's name in columns B+C.

Something like: If the user number '6682660647665664' is seen in column A, look-up the real name for the user number in Column C. Then in column D I want to return "John Doe".

Column A may contain multiple instances of the same User Key, but B and C will only list them once as they're the guide of what the User Key means in human terms.

And there will be multiple User Keys, so it'll need to search the entire list of users.

Let me know if this is beyond the scope of standard Sheets functions and if I need to write a Google App Script instead with some JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this in **B2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "User"", (\d+)")*1, {F2:F*1, G2:G}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Here's an example Sheet I have https://share.getcloudapp.com/geuYOYLK . Column A contains the user keys including the number. F & G contain the guide/legend/key of what the numbers mean. I want column B to return the user's real name, in this example "John Doe".

Comment: Odd, I tried that but it doesn't return anything. The B2 cell is just blank.

Comment: @Weston answer updated to fit your example. try now